# Simulate multimedia key presses in Delphi

Tags: delphi, key, multimedia, simulate, scancodes

I need to simulate pressing of multimedia keys (such as play/pause, prev/next track, rewind/forward, etc.) in Delphi.
I can simulate 'normal' keys easily using the next code:

```
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Also, I've found the lists of MAKE/BREAK codes, but what should I do with them?

MSDN says:

```
VOID keybd_event(
    BYTE bVk,   // virtual-key code
    BYTE bScan, // hardware scan code
    DWORD dwFlags,  // flags specifying various function options
    DWORD dwExtraInfo   // additional data associated with keystroke
   );   
bVk - Specifies a virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254. 
bScan - Specifies a hardware scan code for the key. 
dwFlags - A set of flag bits that specify various aspects of function operation.
    An application can use any combination of the following predefined constant
    values to set the flags: 
    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY - If specified, the scan code was preceded by a 
        prefix byte having the value 0xE0 (224).
    KEYEVENTF_KEYUP If specified, the key is being released. If 
        not specified, the key is being depressed.
dwExtraInfo - Specifies an additional 32-bit value associated with the key stroke.
```

I've found the scan codes for Volume Up:

> Make Code: E0, 32
>   Break Code: E0, F0, 32

I tried:

```
keybd_event(0,$32, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(0,$32, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

but with no luck too (this must simulate E0 32 E0 32, without F0). Also MSDN says bVk must be [1..254], and I used 0 because I haven't found anything suitable in key codes list.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I am sure there is a better solution? Why do so many people decide that faking input is the solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried VK_VOLUME_UP = $AF ?

Comment: I'm codiong IR remote control, so faking input is really what I need :)

Comment: You sure? You can send apps multimedia messages without input faking.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure all multimedia players can handle such messages, but all players I know can handle hotkeys, so it looks to me more univervsal. Or maybe I miss something?

Comment: I don't know whether or not is more universal. Maybe. Anyway, don't use `keybd_event`. Use `SendInput`. The docs for `SendInput` explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me in Delphi XE3:

```
keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP {$AF},0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP,0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

If these constants are not declared in your Delphi version, look at [the table here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/src/Shared/MS/Win32/NativeMethodsOther.cs.html#WindowsBase/src/Shared/MS/Win32/NativeMethodsOther.cs#8ebae4591d9f5d7c)

Comment: Thanks for link to scancode constants! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now it's working Ok.